# How to force nodemon to restart immediatelly after node exits?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I run a `nodemon` with `--inspect-brk` on my remote Linux machine and connect to it from my local MacBook over SSH with local port forwarding.

NOTE: My filesystem I store my code on does not support inotify, so but that's another problem.

When the application exits, `nodemon` just sits there and wait for file changes to occur. I don't want it to wait and simply restart node immediately.

NOTE: I also hooked up a callback on process exit and a bunch of other events, so I can keep inspecting the code.

How do I force nodemon to automatically restart `node` after the script exits/crashes/whatever?

Comment: Why don't you use `forever` instead of `nodemon`. See forever on npm [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)